# Where are the ClearType keys in the Win10 Registry?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, font-smoothing

There is a Microsoft Documentation page about ClearType that claims the registry values are under "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Avalon.Graphics\display names"

source: [Microsoft doc page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/cleartype-registry-settings)

Our Windows 10 machines have no registry folder at all called "Avalon.Graphics" or anything like it. Where are the keys that control ClearType settings?

For informational purposes, I have already set keys in a different location (HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop) to FontSmoothing = 2 (enabled), FontSmoothingGamma = 1200; but all the font on the system is still pixelated. Something has changed and this key is not the only value needed anymore.

Comment: Why do you need to tweak the register keys? There is a setup wizard on the control panel I believe to configure ClearType.

Comment: @Daniel - Fair question. Because I'm a sysadmin for an enterprise environment. I need a registry fix for this to apply at user login. This is not a single workstation problem.